# convergence of functions of random elements in distribution

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am considering the following problem:

Let $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ be the normed spaces (let's say infinite-dimensional) and consider the sequence of random variables $\{X_{n}\}_{n\geq1}$ taking values in $(\mathbf{X}, \mathcal{X})$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is Borel sigma-algebra, which converges in probability to some r.v. $X$, i.e. $X_{n}\stackrel{p}{\to} X$

Let $F_{n}$ be a sequence of continuous functions: $\mathbf{X} \times \mathbf{Y} \to \mathbf{X}$, such that for any $Y\in\mathbf{Y}$ we have 
$$
F_{n}(X_{n},Y) \stackrel{d}{\to} F(X, Y),
$$ 
where $F$ is a continuous function $\mathbf{X} \times \mathbf{Y} \to \mathbf{X}$.

Is it always true that for any sequence of $\{Y_{n}\}_{n\geq1}$ of non-random elements of $\mathbf{Y}$, which converges to some element $Y\in\mathbf{Y}$, we will have
$$
F_{n}(X_{n},Y_{n}) \stackrel{d}{\to} F(X, Y).
$$

I assume it can be truth with some additional requirements on the functions $F_{n}$ and/or on the sequences.

Comment: Don't you need some kind of uniform continuity of the $F_n$ sequence, especially with respect to the 2nd argument?

Comment: @kimchi lover, I have edited the question

Comment: So what have you tried? Why is this problem hard for you?  Do you have some simpler case (say in $\mathbb R^n$) where the answer is obvious?

Comment: @kimchi lover,  I suppose, that in a finite case, in $R^{n}$, this result is the consequence of a Portmanteau Lemma. I would like to have this result in general case

Comment: The Portmanteau lemma I know has only one continuous function $F$, not  a sequence $F_n$.

Comment: @kimchi lover, ok, so then why is it obvious in a finite case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62413/discussion-between-kimchi-lover-and-namev).